# Sigmoid functions in a particular function set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Define a sigmoid as any bounded, odd, increasing function from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a pretty sigmoid as a sigmoid which is convex over $\mathbb{R^-}$ and concave over $\mathbb{R^+}.$

Let $P$ be the smallest set of functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ containing polynomials and closed under exponentiation and product.

If there a function $f$ in $P$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 0$ and $e^f - \frac{1}{2}$ is a (pretty) sigmoid.

Comment: What do you mean, $S$ is "the smallest set of functions"? There are no "seed" elements. For instance, $S$ being the empty set, or the set of constant functions, both satisfy your constraint. Does e.g. $S$ necessarily contain $f(x) = x$?

Comment: Sorry I meant to add that x is in S

Comment: Is there still a mistake in this question? Surely for $x>0$ one wants $f(x)>f(0)$ and $f''(x)<0$, contradicting the last hypothesis in the question -- or have I misunderstood what a sigmoid is?

Comment: Disregarding the assumption about the second derivative, let me make another comment. All the functions in $S$ will extend to holomorphic functions from the complexes to themselves. However none of the examples of sigmoids on Wikipedia seem to have this property.  Could one prove that a sigmoid cannot extend to a holomorphic function on the complexes, or is this asking too much? I have no feeling as to whether one should expect this sort of thing to be true, but if it is true it would serve as a way to attack the question.

Comment: You're right, sign error for $f''$. This is an interesting angle to tackle it.

To be sure, there are some sigmoid like functions in this set:
$exp(-exp(-x+log(log(2))))$ satisfies all properties except for $f(x)+f(-x)=1$. 
$exp(-exp(sinh(-x)+log(log(2))))$ doesn't satisfy the convexity property, nor $f(x)+f(-x)=1$ but not by much.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that lead.

Comment: Isn't the [error function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) a pretty sigmoid function that extends to an entire function?

Comment: Yes, yes it is, d'oh!

Comment: Right, right and so was $exp(-exp(-x)) - exp(-exp(x))$

Comment: This version of the question doesn't seem equivalent to the one you asked originally (at least not obviously). Is there a reason for the change?

Comment: The one at the very beginning: corrected a mistake in the definition of the set of function I'm interested in. The one about entire functions: it seemed like an interesting lead for a little bit, but actually there are plenty of entire functions which are sigmoids.